# method priority, wait another method to finish

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a simple wifi scan app.

I scan the wifis and hold them in a List. When I try to add it ListView, it is always null, but in receiver class I can reach them. How can I fill List before Listing? Here is my code:

> NOTE: I am scanning first then creating fragment.

**WifiReceiver Class**

```
class WifiReceiver : BroadcastReceiver{
    public static List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    public override async void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
        wifiList = wifiManager.ScanResults.ToList();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        wifiManager.StartScan();
    }
}
```

**WifiListFragment Class**

```
public class WifiListFragment : ListFragment {
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<ScanResult> wifiList = WifiReceiver.wifiList.ToList();
        List<string> eliminatedWifi = new List<string>();



        //Some eliminations


        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Application.Context, Resource.Layout.WifiListRow, eliminatedWifi);
        ListAdapter = adapter;

    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.WifiListFragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }


    public override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        base.OnListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My bad sorry, edited.

Comment: You've tried in the activity who calls the fragment call first the service?
Or maybe you can make an object in the activity, and call it from `onCreate()` like `getContext().obj`. Remember that the fragment won't start until activity is fully created. PD: It's an Android answer

Comment: If fragment don't start until activity is fully created, this must work in theory. We started scanning from activity, List filled, and then called fragment with filled List. But don't work.

Comment: That's becuse you call the Service but you don't control if it finished before starting the fragment. Try adding some flag filled by the Service when it has some content to give.

Comment: Yes you are right. I solved it with calling method in onReceive method but i think it is just saved the day, not a proper solution.